# Sql Server 2008 connection fails

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I have two internet connections (let's  say A and B) at my home using two different modem/routers. I am using Sql Server 2008 Express client to connect with a remote Sql Server 2008 server instance.

I can connect easily when I use my internet connection A but never with connection B. It shows me an error given below ...

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name
is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected
host has failed to respond.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

Other than this issue, both connections work perfectly fine. I assumed this to be a firewall issue and tried disabling them but with same result. Also tried specifying TCP/IP, Named Pipes in connection properties but in vain.

Please help.

Comment: did you check if the second router has any rules defined on it? I think that it is probably blocking the ports used by SQL

Comment: I did not see any rules on any of the routers. Tried to reset it to factory settings but that too did not work.

Comment: did you got this i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

this may be a "Surface area" configuration issue - see this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173748%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

remote connections are disabled by default  - see the list of default settings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188980%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

You may also like to review this blog post showing the steps to [enable remote access to sql server express 2008](http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/)

Comment: I am not trying to connect remotely to sql server express 2008. Express edition is on client side (on my laptop). The server which I am connecting remotely is Sql Server 2008 Enterprise.